# Passing data from one desktop/web application to another desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net, desktop-application

I have already running one desktop application in c#.net. Now i want to prepare one desktop/web app. and pass the data to that existing DESKTOP app.

IS it possible ? If it , please provide me any example link.

Edited : 
The existing, say app A, have form like adding student info : name, standards,address, etc. Now my another app , say B (which i have to prepare). so, i want to add same info in B while saving data in B, the data should also be fill up app A form , and save. App A is DESKTOP application. now app B is our choice for selection , whether is it DESKTOP/WEB.

When i add info from app B, it should open the app A form , fill up the info in textbox , which is passed from app B, and then save it automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: What data, what have you tried, what kind of applications, etc. ?

Comment: What kind of data it is?

Comment: The existing, say app A, have form like adding student info : name, standards,address, etc. Now my another app , say B (which i have to prepare). so, i want to add same info in B while saving data in B, the data should also be fill up app A form , and save. App A is DESKTOP application. now app B is our choice for selection , whether   is it DESKTOP/WEB.

Comment: data will be like a student info.

Comment: This is a great question. I don't know why 6 people voted it down. One of the downsides of stack exchange is more than 90% of voted down questions are excellent questions.

Comment: :) I tried it, asking another way : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406684/1758256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share the data between processes using [named-pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes) or windows [.net remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example) This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) discusses different options for inter-process communication, If you want to send data to web site you can expose a `web service`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but still i am in confusion, my existing app is desktop (c#.net), so first quest. is, for second app(which i have to prepare) which app should be easy for me to pass data communication, DESKTOP/WEB ?

Comment: I think web services is more generic and easy solution but if both application are supposed to run on same machine or network and are not being accessed by other applications then you can think of inter-process communication.

Comment: we don't have code of existing app, it's just installed on server.

Comment: I think, web service is perfect solutions. :) Thanks